# How to read from registry from inside driver code?

Tags: c, windows, registry, driver

My machine is a Windows 8 machine. I want to read the "UpperFilters" key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}` from my custom driver to get the presence of filter drivers over USB devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't written a driver since the days of XP, but assuming you're talking about a kernel mode driver I belive you want [`ZwOpenKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`ZwQueryValueKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ZwClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). General guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I required.

Answer (score -2):

[here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67330-read-registry-value/) is code sample to read registry in c

here is a sample:

```
DWORD BufferSize = TOTALBYTES;
DWORD cbData;
DWORD dwRet;

PPERF_DATA_BLOCK PerfData = (PPERF_DATA_BLOCK) malloc( BufferSize );
cbData = BufferSize;

printf("\nRetrieving the data...");

dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
                         TEXT("Global"),
                         NULL,
                         NULL,
                         (LPBYTE) PerfData,
                         &cbData );
while( dwRet == ERROR_MORE_DATA )
{
    // Get a buffer that is big enough.

    BufferSize += BYTEINCREMENT;
    PerfData = (PPERF_DATA_BLOCK) realloc( PerfData, BufferSize );
    cbData = BufferSize;

    printf(".");
    dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
                     TEXT("Global"),
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     (LPBYTE) PerfData,
                     &cbData );
}
if( dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    printf("\n\nFinal buffer size is %d\n", BufferSize);
else printf("\nRegQueryValueEx failed (%d)\n", dwRet);
```

or in a simple example

```
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class", "{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
```

Comment: Nice. Excellent work. Your code works fine in user mode. But this doesn't answer my question. Actually in kernel mode, since I am talking about driver development, malloc and its relatives are not found, instead we have ExAllocatePool() and its relatives. Also the RegXXX() functions aren't available. Instead we have ZwXXX() functions.